# How do I change the data table for a visualization in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have three different Azure DevOps data sources I'm merging together. These three data sources all have the same tables.  I then merged the data into a new set of tables.  However, when I change my data visualizations to point to the new tables, I lose my visualization.  What's the best way to rebind to a new table without having to recreate my visualizations?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of the error that you are getting.

Comment: Add a field from the new table before deleting all the fields from the old one.